# Why is it keep showing deprecated error when running hadoop (or dfs command)

Tags: hadoop, deprecated, hdfs

I've installed *hadoop-2.0.0-alpha*, but whenever I execute a command, it gives me deprecation errors (although it seems like to be running without problem)

```
$ hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input input
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

$ hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -rmr input
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
```

I googled around and it looks like it's a bug for *hadoop-0.23*. However, my version is more recent.

I couldn't find an answer for this version, is it still an existing bug?

Comment: Do you also have a command called "hdfs"? The error message seems to suggest to use that one.

Comment: use ./bin hadoop fs -copyFromLocal input input ;dfs is deprecated.

Comment: Thilo, i cant find command called "hdfs", Animesh, Thanks!! it solved.. i see..

Comment: Looks a bit related to this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138821/error-in-datanode-execution-while-running-hadoop-first-time-in-windows-10/58924939#58924939](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138821/error-in-datanode-execution-while-running-hadoop-first-time-in-windows-10/58924939#58924939)

Answer (score 20):

dfs was deprecated in favor of "fs" command. For example, this:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal input input // this uses FsShell
```

instead of this:

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal input input // this uses the now deprecated HDFS-specific DFSShell
```

Some good background on what the differences were here:

http://nsinfra.blogspot.com/2012/06/difference-between-hadoop-dfs-and.html

Comment: For anyone reading the post recently, use the following instead (CLI was updated about 6-8? months ago):`hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/local/target/file-or-directory /path/to/hdfs/target-directory`
i