# command usage:when to use hadoop fs and hdfs dfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

As the title says, I'm confused when to use commands begining with 'hdfs dfs' and 'hadoop fs'

FYI, I'm hadoop newbie using cloudera 4.6 quickstart vm.

Comment: You have an answer here (first answer) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715082/why-is-it-keep-showing-deprecated-error-when-running-hadoop-or-dfs-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the three commands which appears same but have minute differences

1. **hadoop fs {args}**
2. **hadoop dfs {args}**
3. **hdfs   dfs {args}**

   ```
   hadoop fs <args>
   ```

FS relates to a generic file system which can point to any file systems like local, HDFS etc. So this can be used when you are dealing with different file systems such as Local FS, HFTP FS, S3 FS, and others

```
  hadoop dfs <args>
```

dfs is very specific to HDFS. would work for operation relates to HDFS. This has been deprecated and we should use **hdfs dfs** instead.

```
  hdfs   dfs <args>
```

same as 2nd i.e would work for all the operations related to HDFS and is the recommended command instead of **hadoop dfs**

below is the list categorized as HDFS commands.

```
  **#hdfs commands**
  namenode|secondarynamenode|datanode|dfs|dfsadmin|fsck|balancer|fetchdt|oiv|dfsgroups
```

So even if you use **Hadoop dfs** , it will look locate hdfs and delegate that command to **hdfs dfs**

Comment: So should I use `hdfs fs -put /home/user/localfile.txt hdfs://nameservice1/parent/child` instead of `hdfs dfs -put ...` ?