# ERROR in datanode execution while running Hadoop first time in Windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, datanode

I am trying to run Hadoop 3.1.1 in my Windows 10 machine. I modified all the files:

- hdfs-site.xml
- mapred-site.xml
- core-site.xml
- yarn-site.xml

Then, I executed the following command:

```
C:\hadoop-3.1.1\bin> hdfs namenode -format
```

The format ran correctly so I directed to `C:\hadoop-3.1.1\sbin` to execute the following command:

```
C:\hadoop-3.1.1\sbin> start-dfs.cmd
```

The command prompt opens 2 new windows: one for datanode and another for namenode.

The namenode window keeps running:

```
2018-09-02 21:37:06,232 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-09-02 21:37:06,232 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9000: starting
2018-09-02 21:37:06,247 INFO namenode.NameNode: NameNode RPC up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2018-09-02 21:37:06,247 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Starting services required for active state
2018-09-02 21:37:06,247 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Initializing quota with 4 thread(s)
2018-09-02 21:37:06,247 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Quota initialization completed in 3 milliseconds
name space=1
storage space=0
storage types=RAM_DISK=0, SSD=0, DISK=0, ARCHIVE=0, PROVIDED=0
2018-09-02 21:37:06,279 INFO blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Starting CacheReplicationMonitor with interval 30000 milliseconds
```

While the datanode gives following error:

```
ERROR: datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2762)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2677)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2719)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2863)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2887)
2018-09-02 21:37:04,250 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2018-09-02 21:37:04,250 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

And then, the datanode shuts down! I tried several ways to overcome this error, but this is first time I am installing Hadoop on windows and can't understand what to do next!

Comment: Try changing core-site.xml on the property fs.default.name from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 10):

I got things working, after I removed the file system reference for the datanode in hdfs-site.xml.  I found that enabled the software to create and initialise its own datanode, which then popped up in sbin.  After that I could use hdfs without a hitch.  Here is what worked for me for Hadoop 3.1.3 on windows:

```
<configuration>

<property> 
<name>dfs.replication</name> 
<value>1</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
<value>file:///C:/Users/myusername/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.3/data/namenode</value>
</property> 

<property> 
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
<value>datanode</value>
</property> 

</configuration>
```

Cheers,
MV

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was editing hdfs-site.xml as follows:

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.1.2/data/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.1.2/data/datanode</value>
  </property>
```