# Datanode not working on Hadoop single node cluster on windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs, resourcemanager, datanode

*There are many similar questions on stack overflow but none of them solves my problem.*

I'm trying to start my namenode and datanode, of which namenode starts working but **datanode fails alongwith resource manager and node manager**. Here is the error that shows up:

> 2021-06-17 15:44:09,513 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
> org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:231)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2799)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2714)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2756)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2900)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2924)
> 2021-06-17 15:44:09,518 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
> 2021-06-17 15:44:09,522 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

Here is my *hdfs-site.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\Users\username\Documents\hadoop-3.2.1\data\dfs\namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>C:\Users\username\Documents\hadoop-3.2.1\data\dfs\datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924939/14194692

This answer is not accepted on the question but I tried it and it worked. Tada.

Not deleting my question because none of the question is asked as clearly as this one I believe. I hope it helps other people.

Cheers.